# issue submitting jobs to google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml-engine

I would like to train the object detection model on google cloud, following this post [the link](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9)
Then I follow instructions on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md

I tried to submit a new job. And one of the line is to define dir of the YAML configuration file. This is what I type `--config D:/Racoon/code/raccoon_dataset-master/training/cloud \`
And the configuration file "cloud.yml" is there, but I got this error "ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/Racoon/code/raccoon_dataset-master/training/cloud'"
I am very new to this field. This question might be very stupid, but I really can not figure out what to do. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks. By the way, I am using win10 system.

Answer (score 0):

the --config flag value should be pointing to the file itself not the directory it's in. So you should be passing in the value:

`--config D:/Racoon/code/raccoon_dataset-master/training/cloud.yml`

or

`--config D:/Racoon/code/raccoon_dataset-master/training/cloud/cloud.yml`

Comment: I also tried this. I type cloud.yml and I still got the same error. Any other thought?